# How to use a value in an AJAX callback in PHP code in the same page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is the very first time i am using AJAX. I totally don't understand the flow of data here. please help.and i am doing it in codeigniter
This is my code **EDITED**:

The js function in my view page:

```
    function selectHandler() {
      var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];

      if (selectedItem) {
        var topping = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);

       $.post("http://localhost/offlearn/index.php/ctrl_offapp/trail2",
    {
      top: topping,

    },
    function(res,status){
       // alert(res);
        document.getElementById('tablePrint').innerHTML = res;
    });
    }
    }
```

`trial2` is my controller function.

Can you help?

**The trial2 function in codeigniter is ** :

```
    public function trail2(){
$var=$this->input->post('top');
$data['ts'] = $this->offapp_database->get_tasks();
$data['u'] = $this->offapp_database->usermaster();
print_r($data['ts']);
exit;
$myTable= '<table><tr><td >TASK NAME</td><td >ASSIGNED TO</td><td >CREATED BY</td></tr>';

 foreach($ts->result() as $tk)
     {  
     if ($tk->status ==  0 ) {         
     $myTable.= '<tr><td >'.$tk->taskname.'</td><td >';  foreach($u->result() as $usr)
     { if ($usr->id ==  $tk->assignto) {echo $usr->fname;}}
     $myTable.= '</td><td >';
    foreach($u->result() as $usr)
     { if ($usr->id ==  $tk->createdby ) {echo $usr->fname;}}
     $myTable.=' </td></tr>';
     $myTable.='</table>';
     echo $myTable ;
}
   }    
 }
```

**The functions inthe model**:

```
    public function get_tasks()
    {
     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->from('tasks ');
     $rslt = $this->db->get();
     return $rslt;
     }
   public function usermaster()
  {
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('usersmaster ');
   $rslt = $this->db->get();
   return $rslt;
  }
```

here i tried to display the the table assigned to the variable $myTable in the div 'tableprint' of the view page. 
and this is the output i get:

CI_DB_mysqli_result Object ( [conn_id] => mysqli Object ( [affected_rows] => 108 [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 76b08b24596e12d4553bd41fc93cccd5bac2fe7a $ [client_version] => 50011 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] => [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [field_count] => 19 [host_info] => localhost via TCP/IP [info] => [insert_id] => 0 [server_info] => 5.5.5-10.1.16-MariaDB [server_version] => 50505 [stat] => Uptime: 639 Threads: 1 Questions: 11 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 20 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 13 Queries per second avg: 0.017 [sqlstate] => 00000 [protocol_version] => 10 [thread_id] => 3 [warning_count] => 0 ) [result_id] => mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 14 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 77 [type] => 0 ) [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => [row_data] => )

**Please help me to know where i went wrong**

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You seem to have bad understanding of the way your webpage is generated and handled, and according to your answer I believe it's AJAX which mingled things in your head.

PHP code is interpreted by the server.
JS code is interpreted by the browser.

However, AJAX made it possible to call PHP code from JS code, I believe that's what confuses you.

AJAX consists of sending HTTP requests from JavaScript code and receiving the HTTP response, which allow a developper to, among many other things, send data to a PHP script and receive other data.

But keep in mind that when you do that, the only PHP code that's used by your JS is the code that answers your AJAX request. You can't have PHP code in your page that is magically interpreted by your browser so that it can use data sent by AJAX.

What makes me even more assume that you tried to apply AJAX without understanding it is that the data you receive after your AJAX call has been presumably made and transmitted by PHP, why not apply whatever PHP code you want to apply on that res data at that point, before your PHP code sends it to your page ?

Comment: thankyou for the response. I think i will have to learn a little AJAX to know how it works.

Comment: @AnnaMary if his answer helped you, you should upvote it or select it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Generate the HTML in http://localhost/offlearn/index.php/ctrl_offapp/trail2 and return it.

Then, in the AJAX callback, set the html with the following:
...

```
}, function(res, status) {
    $('#tablePrint').html(res);
});
```

...

Comment: Thankyou for the response. I used it and i generated the html table in that controller function(which is mentioned in the the url) ,i assigned the html table to a variable $myTable using single qoutes,everything is working except the php lines.

Comment: I have made some changes to my code and its working better,but the out put isnt right. canyou please help me find out where i went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should be more clear to ask a question as I do understand your function is a javascript function which you can call like this in your code.

```
function selectHandler() {
  var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
  if (selectedItem) {
    var topping = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
    $.post("http://localhost/offlearn/index.php/ctrl_offapp/trail2", {
      top: topping,  
    }, function(res, status) {
      //alert(res);
      test(res);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the response

Comment: Sorry - What I meant was write the entire top() function in PHP, then echo it. That echo will be assigned to res in the AJAX request.

Comment: Now i have added all functions in the mvc